# SharePoint-hosted SharePoint Add-in Client Web Part ListViewWebPart and App Web list

Tags: visual-studio, sharepoint, office365, web-parts

I'm struggling with implementing a Client Web Part for a SharePoint-hosted Add-in to display list data from a list in app web.

Actually it is not possible to place my Web Part code:

```
<WebPartPages:WebPartZone runat="server" FrameType="TitleBarOnly" ID="full" Title="loc:full" >
  <WebPartPages:XsltListViewWebPart ID="XsltListViewWebPart" runat="server" ListUrl="Lists/MyList" IsIncluded="True" NoDefaultStyle="TRUE" Title="Mitarbeiter" PageType="PAGE_NORMALVIEW" Default="False" ViewContentTypeId="0x"> 
  </WebPartPages:XsltListViewWebPart>
</WebPartPages:WebPartZone>
```

in the auto-generated *.aspx page when creating a new Client Web Part.
How can i achieve my goal?

P.S. I'm using SP2013 Enterprise and VS2015.

Kind regards